# what's wrong with my class definition?

Tags: java, compilation

Why won't this class compile?

```
class Exam {

private int score;

    // constructor initializes score to 99
    public  void Exam() {
        score = 99;
    }

    // returns the current value of score
    private int getScore() {
       return score;
    }

    // returns the String representation of the Object
    public String toString() {
        return "The score is " + getScore();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Why won't you share the compiler's error message with us?

Answer (score 7):

Your constructor shouldn't have a return type. Not even void.

```
public Exam() {
    score = 99;
}
```

Comment: Damned... Only approximately seven thousand milliseconds faster then me.

Comment: @user703430 If Mark's answer was the solution, please mark his answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

A construct should not contain the `void` keyword:

```
public Exam() {
    score = 99;
}
```

A constructor returns a reference the the newly created object. But you don't have to write it. So thinking it is `void` is wrong as well.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors don't need return types.  Remove void and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

In a constructor you don't use `void`.

Write the constructor as:

```
public Exam() { 
    score = 99; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the missing package declaration.

```
package yourpkg;

class Exam {
```

Additionally, the return type on the for `Exam()` makes it a function instead of a constructor and will result in a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion not related to the concrete problem:

```
private int score;

// returns the current value of score
private int getScore() {
   return score;
}
```

There is no point in having that `getScore()` if your going to keep it `private`. Make it `public`.

Also, always use the `@Override` annotation whenever your intention is to override some method. Compiler will let you known in case you are failing to do so. That means bug prevention.

e.g.

```
// returns the String representation of the Object
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "The score is " + getScore();
}
```